# mysql percentage difference from previous row

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I calculate % difference for each previous row in mysql?

I was able to get this to work, but if my `date` column is not consecutive, I'm not sure how to pull it dynamically:

```
SELECT c1.date, 
       c1.total, 
       ( ( c1.total - ifnull(c2.total, 0) ) / c1.total ) AS percentage_change 
FROM   table c1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table c2 
                    ON c1.id = c2.id 
                       AND c1.date - c2.date = 1 
ORDER  BY c1.date DESC 
LIMIT  30
```

The trouble with this is that my `date` column is not necessarily `c1.total - c2.total = 1`

One idea I just had is to do a subquery and `select where c2.date < c1.date order by c2.date DESC LIMIT 1`. I think that'll pick the next lowest date value, so trying that now.

Comment: Boy oh boy, people making a meal out of this one, aren't they?! Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you could do it:

```
SELECT current.id, current.date, ((current.total - IFNULL(prev.total, 0)) / current.total) AS percentage_change
FROM
(SELECT c1.id, c1.total, count(c2.*) as ordinal
FROM some_table AS c1, some_table AS c2
WHERE c2.date < c1.date) AS curr

OUTER JOIN (SELECT c1.id, c1.total, count(c2.*) as ordinal
FROM some_table AS c1, some_table AS c2
WHERE c2.date < c1.date) AS prev
    ON curr.ordinal - 1 = prev.ordinal;
```

Assuming you don't have any rows with the same date (and assuming I don't have any typos in my syntax), this will work. However I would recommend against this if it can be avoided.

My preferred solution would be to use this (a MUCH more efficient query):

```
SELECT * FROM some_table ORDER BY date ASC;
```

And then do the math inside of your application (whatever it is) as you iterate through the result set.

Comment: Thanks! yea I think calculating outside of SQL will be much easier. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt, not 100% sure it is working yet and curious if there's a better way without using 3 tables

```
SELECT c1.date, 
       c1.total, 
       ( ( c1.total - Ifnull((SELECT c3.date 
                              FROM   table c3 
                              WHERE  c3.date < c1.date 
                              ORDER  BY c3.date DESC 
                              LIMIT  1), 0) 
                       ) / c1.total ) AS percentage_change 
FROM   table c1 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table c2 
                    ON c1.id = c2.id 
                       AND c1.date - c2.date = 1 
ORDER  BY c1.date DESC 
LIMIT  30
```